# Proof Check: A subspace of a separable metric space is separable.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I just begin to learn Analysis by myself. Can someone please help me check my proof about A subspace of a separable metric space is separable to see any errors in math, logic and English. Thank you so much!!

> **Fact:** Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and let $S\subseteq X$. Then $$clS=\{x\in X:N\bigcap S\neq\emptyset\text{ for all $N\in N_x$}\}.$$

Theorem: Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space and let $(Y,d_Y)$ be a subspace of $(X,d)$. Then $(Y,d_Y)$ is a separable space.

Proof:Let $C=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots\}$ be a dense countable subset of $X$. Let $$\mathbb{A}=\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}^+:\text{ there exists $y\in Y$ such that $d(y,x_n)<\frac{1}{m}$ }(x_n\in C)\}.$$ For each $(n,m)\in\mathbb{A}$, let $y_{n,m}\in Y$ such that $d(y_{n,m},x_n)<\frac{1}{m}$. Then $C_Y=\{y_{n,m}:(n,m)\in\mathbb{A}\}$ is a countable subset of $Y$. Let $y\in Y$, let $\epsilon>0$, and let $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $\frac{1}{m}\leqslant\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $C$ is dense in $X$, $clC=X$. Thus $y\in Y\subseteq X=clC$. By the Fact, there exists an open ball $B_\frac{1}{m}(y)$ centered at $y$ with radius $\frac{1}{m}$ in $X$ such that $B_\frac{1}{m}(y)\bigcap C\neq\emptyset$. Thus there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in B_\frac{1}{m}(y)$. It implies that $d(y,x_n)<\frac{1}{m}$. It follows that $(n,m)\in\mathbb{A}$. So, $$d(y,y_{n,m})\leqslant d(y,x_n)+d(x_n,y_{n,m})<\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m}\leqslant\epsilon.$$ Hence, $y_{n,m}\in B_\epsilon(y)\bigcap Y$, and $B_\epsilon(y)\bigcap Y\neq\emptyset$. Let $D$ be the closure of $C_Y$ in $Y$. Then by the Fact again, $y\in D$. Thus $Y\subseteq D$. Since $D\subseteq Y$, $Y=D$. Therefore, $(Y,d_Y)$ is a separable space.

Comment: Alternatively use the two facts: A metric space is separable iff it is second countable. A subspace of a second countable space is second countable.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Thanks for you reply. But is my proof correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes it seems fine to me.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Thank you!

Comment: Very good proof.  BTW if $C$ is  a dense subset of $X$ then $\{B_q(x): x\in C,\;q\in \Bbb Q\}$ is a base so if $X$ is separable then $X$ is second-countable.